# Sorting result of mysql join by avg of third table?

Tags: mysql, sorting, join

I have three tables.

One table contains submissions which has about 75,000 rows
One table contains submission ratings and only has < 10 rows
One table contains submission => competition mappings and for my test data also has about 75,000 rows.

What I want to do is

> Get the top 50 submissions in a round of a competition.
>   Top is classified as highest average rating, followed by highest amount of votes

Here is the query I am using which works, but the problem is that it takes over 45 seconds to complete! I profiled the query (results at bottom) and the bottlenecks are copying the data to a tmp table and then sorting it so how can I speed this up?

```
 SELECT `submission_submissions`.* 
   FROM `submission_submissions`
   JOIN `competition_submissions` 
     ON `competition_submissions`.`submission_id` = `submission_submissions`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `submission_ratings` 
     ON `submission_submissions`.`id` = `submission_ratings`.`submission_id`
  WHERE `top_round` =  1 
    AND `competition_id` =  '2'
    AND `submission_submissions`.`date_deleted` IS NULL
GROUP BY submission_submissions.id
ORDER BY AVG(submission_ratings.`stars`) DESC, 
         COUNT(submission_ratings.`id`) DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

#### submission_submissions

```
CREATE TABLE `submission_submissions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goals` text,
  `submission` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `genre` (`genre`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `date_created` (`date_created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115037 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### submission_ratings

```
CREATE TABLE `submission_ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `submission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stars` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `submission_id` (`submission_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `stars` (`stars`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### competition_submissions

```
CREATE TABLE `competition_submissions` (
  `competition_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `submission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `top_round` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`submission_id`),
  KEY `competition_id` (`competition_id`),
  KEY `top_round` (`top_round`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### SHOW PROFILE Result (ordered by duration)

```
state                 duration (summed) in sec percentage
Copying to tmp table  33.15621                 68.46924
Sorting result        11.83148                 24.43260
removing tmp table     3.06054                  6.32017
Sending data           0.37560                  0.77563
... insignificant amounts removed ...
Total                  48.42497               100.00000
```

#### EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type  table                    type         possible_keys                     key                       key_len  ref                                              rows   Extra                                                                                                 
1   SIMPLE       competition_submissions  index_merge  PRIMARY,competition_id,top_round  competition_id,top_round  4,5                                                       18596  Using intersect(competition_id,top_round); Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
1   SIMPLE       submission_submissions   eq_ref       PRIMARY                           PRIMARY                   4        inkstakes.competition_submissions.submission_id  1      Using where                                                                                           
1   SIMPLE       submission_ratings       ALL          submission_id                                                                                                         5      Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
```

Comment: *"One table contains submission ratings and only has < 10 rows"* - some mistake, surely? Not only are you including selection criteria on the ratings table, but you are then sorting by average stars and total ratings from the ratings table, which is then used to determine the top **50** submissions.

Comment: Well it's my testing data, I've not pumped that table full yet, so presently it only has < 10 rows, regardless though because I use a left join even results with no ratings should be included...

Comment: How do you want to rank results with no ratings? Your existing `order by` is purely related to aggregated values from the ratings table, yet with  <10 rows on that table at least 40 of your top 50 rows are not going to have *any* ratings.

Comment: Well with the real data it is far more likely to about a 3:1 ratio of ratings to submissions. results with no ratings can be listed after the results with ratings; in reality we really don't care about results with no ratings; We may even just filter them out with a standard join at some point.

Comment: (Correction to my original comment: I have subsequently noticed that the WHERE clause criteria are on submission_submissions and competition_submissions values, not ratings values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in reality you won't be interested in unrated submissions, and that a given submission only has a single `competition_submissions` entry for a given match and top_round, I suggest:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM (SELECT `submission_id`, 
             AVG(`stars`) AvgStars, 
             COUNT(`id`) CountId
      FROM `submission_ratings` 
      GROUP BY `submission_id`
      ORDER BY AVG(`stars`) DESC, COUNT(`id`) DESC
      LIMIT 50) r
JOIN `submission_submissions` s
  ON r.`submission_id` = s.`id` AND
     s.`date_deleted` IS NULL
JOIN `competition_submissions` c
  ON c.`submission_id` = s.`id` AND 
     c.`top_round` =  1 AND
     c.`competition_id` = '2'
ORDER BY r.AvgStars DESC, 
         r.CountId DESC
```

(If there is more than one `competition_submissions` entry per submission for a given match and top_round, then you can add the GROUP BY clause back in to the main query.)

If you do want to see unrated submissions, you can union the results of this query to a LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL query.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick that works on MySql and helps to avoid copying/sorting huge temp tables in queries like this (with LIMIT X).
Just avoid `SELECT *`, this copies all columns to the temporary table, then this huge table is sorted, and in the end, the query takes only 50 records from this huge table ( 50 / 70000 = 0,07 % ).

Select only columns that are really necessary to perform sort and limit, and then join missing columns only for selected 50 records by id.

```
select ss.*
from submission_submissions ss
join (
            SELECT `submission_submissions`.id, 
                    AVG(submission_ratings.`stars`) stars,
                    COUNT(submission_ratings.`id`) cnt
               FROM `submission_submissions`
               JOIN `competition_submissions` 
                 ON `competition_submissions`.`submission_id` = `submission_submissions`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `submission_ratings` 
                 ON `submission_submissions`.`id` = `submission_ratings`.`submission_id`
              WHERE `top_round` =  1 
                AND `competition_id` =  '2'
                AND `submission_submissions`.`date_deleted` IS NULL
            GROUP BY submission_submissions.id
            ORDER BY AVG(submission_ratings.`stars`) DESC, 
                     COUNT(submission_ratings.`id`) DESC
              LIMIT 50
) xx
ON ss.id = xx.id
ORDER BY xx.stars DESC, 
         xx.cnt DESC;
```